# TeamCity Build Agent Shows All Build Steps Incompatible

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy, build-agent

I've recently installed TeamCity 2017.2.3 (build 541047) and Octopus Deploy 2018.1.5 and originally was having success running builds and creating packages in TeamCity, but now my build agent shows all of my build steps as incompatible after a service restart.

[image]

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the buildagent, plugins (I use Node.JS build runner, Octopus Deploy integration, and xUnit) and rebuilt each of the build steps, but still run into the same problem

Build Step List
[image]

[image]

Anyone know what would be causing this issue?

Comment: What properties are the build agent(s) showing? It is looking for either environment or system properties that match the above.

Comment: @Bronumski -Sorry for the delay.  System Properties, Environmental Variables, and  Configuration Parameters are all empty for the BuildAgent.  The only parameters I'm using at all for my build steps are for versioning based on http://thefatcoder.com/continuous-integration/building-and-deploying-with-teamcity-and-octopus-deploy-part-4-of-4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each agent should have a list of global parameters that are picked up from the OS or manually configured from the agent properties file on the machine. These are things like the path, dotnet versions, npm etc.

`http(s)://<tc root>/agentDetails.html?id=<agent id>&tab=agentParameters`

(You can get to the above by clicking on the agent you want to inspect)

[image]

You can then override or add to these from the root project all the way up the project tree to the build configuration.

The message you are getting is saying is that in order for the build to run it needs to have an agent with those parameters configured. Could you give a screen grab of what your build agent parameters are.

Here is an example from one of my build agents which shows some of the configuration parameters that you need.

[image]

You should not need to add these, they should be picked up automatically by the agent.

- First make sure these dependencies are actually installed.
- If missing install and restart the agent service (required to pick up new configuration properties).
- Possibly try a machine restart in case newly installed components require a reboot.
- Failing that check to see what permissions the build agent service is running under. It might not have permissions needed to poll the system but I have never seen that.

Comment: I've updated my post to show my Agent Parameters (or lack of them).  It's like all of them were removed, though I'm not sure how that would have even happened.  I was hoping uninstalling / reinstalling the agent would resolve it, but it made no difference.  Are these stored in a config somewhere in The BuildAgent folder or in the registry?

Comment: @GaryJames - You can add them to the agent manually using the agent config file but the majority of them should be auto discovered by the agent hence my suggestion about permissions. Are you hosting this on a physical machine, in the cloud or some other virtualisation?

Comment: I'm looking into the permissions right now to see if something changed, so I'll let you know soon what I find out.  TC was installed using a service account, so I'll see if the permissions to the build agent fell off or something.  This is hosted on a VM.

Comment: Completely removed the build agent again, rebooted, then installed ensuring the account I was using had the correct permissions and it worked!  I'll have to adjust the service account it should be using to ensure the permissions will work on that.  Thanks for your help.